# expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c, brackets

I have following code in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NOERROR 0

int c;
int parentheses, brackets, braces;

void checkErrors(void);

int main()
{
    extern int parentheses, brackets, braces;
    extern int c;

    parentheses=0; brackets=0; braces=0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '(')
            {++parentheses;}
        else if (c == ')')
            {--parentheses;}
        else if (c == '[')
            {++brackets;}
        else if (c == ']')
            {--brackets;}
        else if (c == '{')
            {++braces;}
        else if (c == '}')
            {--braces;}
    checkErrors();
}

void checkErrors(void)
{   
    extern int parentheses, brackets, braces;
    extern int c;

    if (parentheses != NOERROR){
        printf("You have missed some parentheses"); 
        }

    if (brackets != NOERROR){
        printf("You have missed some brackets");
        }

    if (braces != NOERROR){
        printf("You have missed some braces");
        }
}
```

I receive this error: expected declaration or statement at end of input on line 55 (when main function ends) Why is this happening? I didn't miss any brackets.

Thanks

Comment: "I didn't miss any brackets" - um, yes you did. Your code, aligned by brackets, [see here](http://pastebin.com/Zshb6rT4). Whether it is the closing bracket of the while loop or the closing bracket of `main()` I leave to you to decide, but your closing statement in your question is false regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The statement after while is invalid. Before the else if there shall be if

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    else if (c == '(')
```

Also the while statement shall have the closing brace.

Place closing braces after these statements

```
      else if (c == '}')
            {--braces;}
   } // <==
```

Comment: there was a if, but i deleted it and I forgot to delete else. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You never closed the while loop in your main().

Answer (score 0):

While loop is not closed by `}`.
Use good editor.

Use Switch case as it is more readable for lots of condition.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
switch (c)
      {
                case '(':
                    ++parentheses;
                    break;
                case ')':
                    --parentheses;
                    break;
                case '[':
                    ++brackets;
                    break;
                case ']':
                    --brackets;
                    break;
                case '{':
                    ++braces;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    --braces;
                    break;
      }
}
```